# EJBCA 403 forbidden on Wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, ear, ejbca

I have a problem with an EJBCA 8 deployment on Wildfly 26.1.3.Final
Whenever i try to access a public endpoint i get a 403 forbidden HTTP status back.

This is my configuration:

wildfly.service

```
[Unit]
Description=The WildFly Application Server
After=syslog.target network.target
Before=httpd.service

[Service]
Environment=LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1
EnvironmentFile=-/opt/kais/mes/install/guardian/wildfly/wildfly-26.1.3.Final/docs/contrib/scripts/systemd/wildfly.conf
User=vagrant
LimitNOFILE=102642
PIDFile=/opt/kais/mes/workdir/guardian/wildfly/wildfly.pid
ExecStart=/opt/kais/mes/install/guardian/wildfly/wildfly-26.1.3.Final/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone.xml  -b 10.0.0.16 -bmanagement=10.0.0.16
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

These are the bash commands that I use to deploy EJBCA ear on Wildfly

```
cd /opt/kais/mes/install/guardian/ejbca/ejbca-ce-EJBCA_8_0_20230531

# Deploy ear
sudo ant deployear -Dappserver.home=/opt/kais/mes/install/guardian/wildfly/wildfly-26.1.3.Final
```

Another thing to note is that I do not get any logs regarding the 403 from the Wildfly server logs -> $WILDFLY_HOME/standalone/log/server.log

Answer (score 0):

There are many public end points, which one are you trying to access? For protocols like SCEP, CMP, EST, REST etc there is a configuration in the Admin UI to allow or disallow them. A 403 is a quite specific one, so something specific must make it forbidden.